# WiFi not working due to WiFi button problem

Tags: wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

I have an HP Pavilion dv6, and I've been having problems with the sound controls and WiFi swith. Those are touch controls above the keyboard.

I opened the laptop and saw that the flat wire that connects those controls with the motherboard is partially broken.

From that moment, the controls seems disconnected as they don't show any light. However, the WiFi switch is turned off. If I try to turn it on, it doesn't stay at "on" and go to "off" again.

I've been reading different forums, but I haven't been able to solve my problem.

The results of `iwconfig` are:

```
enp3s0    no wireless extension.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abg ESSID:off/any
    Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated
    Retry short limit:7    RTS thr:off    Fragment thr:off
    Por Management:off 

lo    no wireless extensions.
```

The results of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN 
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

What should I do to ignore the defective WiFi button?

Comment: It may be possible to set the wifi on in bios, but it would seem unlikely that there is a software solution from the operating system.

Comment: You may be able to purchase the cable from [HP Parts](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00372736)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions!

As @Charles Green suggested, I tried to set the wifi on in the bios. I didn't find the option to do so, but I restored the default options for the bios. After rebooting, `rfkill list all` result was:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

And finally, the wifi worked! :)